# Rails associations has_many

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I currently have a model: User, and I want the ability to add to each user has_many friend_requests. Would I have to create another model that is titled model: "Friend_Request" which contains belongs_to :user? Or how would I go about doing this.  I would like the user to have many friend_requests while also being able to request_friendship.  I am totally lost in this, can someone help me. Thank you in advance.

```
 Note: This is for rails 4, if that matters.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you would need two models for this. Anytime you use `has_many` or `belongs_to` you need a model for each part of the relationship.

So, here, you need:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :friend_requests
end

class FriendRequest < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :friend
end

class Friend < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :friend_requests
end
```

You will then need `users` and `friend_requests` tables. Like so:

```
class CreateUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :users do |t|
      t.string :name
    end
  end
end

class CreateFriendRequests < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :friend_requests do |t|
      t.integer :user_id
      t.integer :friend_id
    end
  end
end


class CreateFriends < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :friends do |t|
      t.string :name
    end
  end
end
```

Hope that helps! Good luck!

Comment: how would you model who requested the friendship in your association?

Comment: I would add in a model for Friend and add in `belongs_to :friend` in the FriendRequest model. Like this:                                      `class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :friend_requests
end`

`class FriendRequest < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :friend
end`

`class Friend < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :friend_requests
end`. See changes in code above!

Answer (score 0):

No matter which rails version you using this is about model of reality. I would suggest to add following model

```
class CreateContactRequests < ActiveRecord::Migrations
  def change
    create_table :contact_requests do |t|
      t.references :owner
      t.references :user
      t.string :type #incoming/outcoming
    end
  end
end

class User
  has_many :freinds_requests, -> { where("contact_requests.type = 'outcoming ")}, :foreign_key => 'owner_id', :class => "ContactRequest"
  has_many :requested_freindships, -> { where("contact_requests.type = 'incoming ")}, :foreign_key => 'owner_id', :class => "ContactRequest"
end

class ContactRequest
  belongs_to :owner, :class_name => 'User'
  belongs_to :user
end
```